# If a source code repository has different set of files like java, jsp, html etc, how to ensure all their dependencies are in place?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If a source code repository has different set of files like java, jsp, html etc, how to ensure all their dependencies are in place? and how will the build file look like?